# How to make the Android Project of my Xamarin app start with MainApplication.cs instead of MainActivity.cs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on a `Xamarin.Forms` application that has `Xamarin.Android` and `Xamarin.ios` projects. I need to use the `CurrentActivityPlugin` for Android.

I need to perform some functionality when the Android app starts, hence I want to my app to begin with a `MainApplicaiton` instead of a `MainActivity` as shown in the docs [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin).

And ideas on how I can refactor the Android Project to begin with a `MainApplication` instead of `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AssemblyInfo.cs remove this:

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: Application(Debuggable=true)]
#else
[assembly: Application(Debuggable = false)]
#endif
```

Then add it to your MainApplication like this:

```
#if DEBUG
[Application(Debuggable = true)]
#else
[Application(Debuggable = false)]
#endif
   public class MainApplication : global::Android.App.Application
   {      
      public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer): base(handle, 
        transer)
      {
      }

      public override void OnCreate()
      {
        base.OnCreate();
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this);

        //A great place to initialize Xamarin.Insights and Dependency Services! Add 
         some function that you want.
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

> And ideas on how I can refactor the Android Project to begin with a MainApplication instead of MainActivity?

According to the link that you provided, if you want to Android project start with MainApplication, you just create new class name MainApplication.cs in Android project, if you want to perform some functions when Android project starts, you just add some code that you want in OnCreate() method.

```
#if DEBUG
[Application(Debuggable = true)]
#else
[Application(Debuggable = false)]
#endif
public class MainApplication : global::Android.App.Application
{      
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer): base(handle, transer)
    {
    }
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this);

        //A great place to initialize Xamarin.Insights and Dependency Services! Add some function that you want.
    }

}
```

You can see when you run project,enter  MainApplication firstly, then Mainactivity,I think the article that you provided, has solved your question.

Comment: Yh I know to do this, but when I simply add this file with the code above I get a build error. Seems there is more to it than just adding this file, Maybe some way to specifically indicate that this is the starting point of your app, and begin the main Activity from here or something.

Comment: @Kikanye What is error message? I don't have any issue when register Application, this is my sample:https://github.com/CherryBu/testapp.An activity is a class that represents one screen in an Android application. It is a reusable piece of UI with its own life cycle, but it is always loaded in a process that has an Application instance as well. So I think the just Application instance can meet your requirement.

Comment: The error was a System.InvalidOperationException which said Application cannot have both a type with an [Application] attribute and an [assembly:Application] attribute